# jquery - check for required but empty checkbox, multiselect, radio and drop field

Tags: jquery

With the help of the stackoverflowers, I got this piece of code working within my sample app, but someone in the forum pointed out that I will need more code to validate a checkbox, radio, multiselect and dropdown.  Right now, this works to validate an empty text field.

I'm think if I do a find for the types of the required fields might work, but I have no idea how to incorporate this or if it would even work.  Could someone provide assistance please/

**my jsfiddle**>> http://jsfiddle.net/justmelat/kBDNt/

**my html code**>>

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <div id="holdErrMsg"></div>
    <fieldset id="mainSection" name="mainSection">
                <legend style="color:blue; font-weight:bold">Project Overview Section</legend>

                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 33px; width: 178px;">Name</td>
                        <td style="height: 33px"><input  id="1125" name="1125" class="1125-required" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 33px; width: 178px;">Email</td>
                        <td style="height: 33px"><input id="1026" name="1026" class="1026-required" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 178px">Product Title</td>
                        <td><input  id="1089" name="1089" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 178px">Product Type</td>
                        <td><select id="1169" name="1169">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                        <option value="Cars">Cars</option>
                        <option value="Boats">Boats</option>
                        <option value="Planes">Planes</option>
                        </select></td>
                    </tr>
                                        <tr><td>
                                        <button id="btnCatchReqFlds" type="button" name="btn">Check Required Fields</button>
                                        </td></tr>
                                    </table>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset id="section-11" name="section-11">
                <legend style="color:fuchsia; font-weight:bold">Car Details Section</legend>

                <table cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px; height: 35px"><label>Size:*</label></td>
                        <td style="height: 35px"><input id="1245" class="1245-required" name="1245" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 35px; width: 334px">Color:*</td>
                        <td style="height: 35px">
                        <select id="1433" class="1433-required" name="1433">
                <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
                        <option value="Blank">Blank</option>
                        <option value="Green">Green</option>
            </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px">Description:</td>
                        <td>
                        <textarea id="1290" name="1290" rows="2" style="width: 433px"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                            </fieldset>

            <fieldset id="section-12" name="section-12">
                <legend style="color:fuchsia; font-weight:bold">Plane Details Section</legend>

                <table cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px; height: 35px"><label>Size:</label></td>
                        <td style="height: 35px"><input id="1245" name="1245" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 35px; width: 334px">Color*:</td>
                        <td style="height: 35px">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="1433[]" id="1433[]" value"Orange" class="1433[]-required"/>Orange
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="1433[]" id="1433[]" value"Blue" class="1433[]-required"/>Blue
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="1433[]" id="1433[]" value"Green" class="1433[]-required"/>Green
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px">Description:</td>
                        <td>
                        <textarea id="1290" name="1290" rows="2" style="width: 433px"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="section-13" name="section-13">
                <legend style="color:fuchsia; font-weight:bold">Boat Details Section</legend>

                <table cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px; height: 35px"><label>Size:</label></td>
                        <td style="height: 35px"><input id="1245" name="1245" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 35px; width: 334px">Color:*</td>
                        <td style="height: 35px">
                                                <input type="radio" name="1834" id="1834" value="None" class="valuetext" class="1834-required">None
                                                <input type="radio" name="1834" id="1834" value="All" class="valuetext" class="1834-required">All
                       </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px">Description:</td>
                        <td>
                        <textarea id="1290" name="1290" rows="2" style="width: 433px"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                            </fieldset><br>
<fieldset id="section-1011" name="section-1011">
                <legend style="color:green; font-weight:bold">Misc Info Section</legend>

                <table cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px; height: 35px"><label>Size:</label></td>
                        <td style="height: 35px"><input id="1301" name="1301" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 35px; width: 334px">Color:</td>
                        <td style="height: 35px">
                        <select id="1302" name="1302">
                <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
                        <option value="Blank">Blank</option>
                        <option value="Green">Green</option>
            </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px">Description:</td>
                        <td>
                        <textarea id="1303" name="1303" rows="2" style="width: 433px"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                            </fieldset>


</form>​
```

**my jquery code**>>

```
$("#section-11").hide();
$("#section-12").hide();
$("#section-13").hide();
$("#section-1011").hide();

var projtype = new Array(
        {value : 'Cars', sect_id : 'fieldset#section-11'},
        {value : 'Planes', sect_id : 'fieldset#section-12'},
        {value : 'Boats', sect_id : 'fieldset#section-13'}
    );
$("select#1169").on('change',function () {
var thisVal = $(this).val();
 var sect_id ="";
     //$('fieldset[id!="mainSection"]').hide();
    $(projtype).each(function() {
$(this.sect_id).hide();
        if(this.value == thisVal) {
        $(this.sect_id).show();
        }
    });        
});

$("#btnCatchReqFlds").on('click', function() {
    var requiredButEmpty = $("fieldset:visible").find('input[class*="-required"], select[class*="-required"]').filter(function() {
      return $.trim($(this).val()) === "";  
    });
    if (requiredButEmpty.length) {
        requiredButEmpty.each(function () {

            $("#holdErrMsg").append("Please fill in the " + this.name + "<br />");
        });
    }
    return !requiredButEmpty.length;
});
​
```

Comment: tip, instead doing alot of hide's, try improving `$(element,element,element).hide();`

Comment: thank you - good suggestion, I updated my jsfiddle with this.